# How to convert DOCX OR DOC to HTML With image using phpWord

Tags: php, phpword

Hi I need to convert DOCX to HTML with image and style.

Here is my code example

```
$source = "Sampledocx.docx";
$fileheader = 'test';
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);     
$htmlWriter=\PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord,'HTML');
$htmlWriter->save(storage_path('app/public/html/'.$fileheader.'.html'));
```

I'm not getting any error it is converting into html but without image.

What do I need to change in order to keep the image?